# Живой элемент на layout

Tags: java, android, android-animation, vector-drawable

Реализовать примерно следующее:
1. На layout добавить графический элемент (дым)
2. Наш дым должен иметь базовую анимацию(шевелится)
3. Наш дым умеет реагировать на действия пользователя(перемещение при нажатии кнопки)
4. Наш дым имеет самый низкий индекс и находится под всеми элементами
5. Наш дым умеет обрабатывать нажатия, двойные нажатия, свайпы(анимация)
6. Наш дым перетекает на другой фрагмент, если мы его поменяем.

Подскажите, с чего начать? Я пока вообще не понимаю, как это реализовать? Это должна быть векторная графика и её последующая анимация? Или что то другой?

Comment: Начните с создания кастомного View в котором будет происходить анимация. Если вы еще не изучали, советую по подробней это сделать, в нем есть все нужные инструменты. Дым можно определить как Path - это графика. Создать анимацию  с помощью потоков... Ну или поискать какую то библиотеку

Comment: Потоки - в смысле в отдельном потоке, что бы не блочить ui поток?

Comment: Вы все правильно поняли